# JQuery selector by attribute value?

Tags: jquery, attributes, selector

I have the following variable:

```
var rowId = row.id;
```

the value of row.id is 0fe92ed4-b224-4140-b389-85a19fdbfdd6

if I create the selector like that:

```
$("tr[id='row.id']")
```

It isn't working. But if I type directly:

```
$("tr[id='0fe92ed4-b224-4140-b389-85a19fdbfdd6']")
```

It's working as espected. Why is that and how to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
$("tr[id="+row.id+"]")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `+` concat operator :-

```
$("tr[id='" + row.id + "']")
```